# Perché i giovani dicono 'Bella Zio'?

Tags: meaning, phrase-origin, neologism

'Bella Zio' è un'espressione molto in voga tra i giovani italiani.  Cosa significa e che origine ha?

Comment: A me risulta che è una cosa di Roma.

Comment: Qui a Venezia (e dintorni) non ho mai sentito una cosa del genere. Sarà che non sono più giovane?

Comment: @MarioVernari - prova a chiedere a qualche adolescente della zona :).

Comment: @Josh61, sicuramente lo farò. Tuttavia tieni conto che in Veneto il dialetto è usatissimo, persino nei luoghi istuzionali. Questo per sottolineare che in Italia ci sono notevolissime differenze già tra città e città.

Comment: mai usata in tutta la mia vita questa espressione, e i mie amici, giovani anche loro, idem (viviamo tutti in Sicilia)!

Answer (score 18):

Non è un'espressione veramente moderna, diciamo che è tornata di moda. "Bella zio" esiste da un bel po'.

-Origine: nasce molto probabilmente nei sobborghi milanesi almeno almeno 20 anni fa, e data l'etimologia incerta, penso che la sua nuova ridiffusione attuale sia dovuta ai testi rap tipo J-ax, club Dogo o Fabri Fibra.

-Significato: si dice  quando si è d'accordo tipo per un appuntamento o è stata fatta la cosa "giusta". Si presume che "zio" sia l'equivalente nostrano dell'americano "bro", brother (fratello), tipo appellativo nell'ambito ghetto/rap/gangsta music made in USA.

-Esempio 1: "Ci vediamo alle 4?" Risposta: "Bella zio." In seguito si può battere il 5, unire i pugni o altri siparietti manuali (più o meno coordinati). In caso negativo puoi rispondere: "No zio, non ci sto dentro".

-Esempio 2: "Mi son comprato la nuova PS." Risposta: "Bella
 zioooo, sei un grande!!"

-Esempio 3: "Non ho fatto i compiti." Risposta: "Bella zio, troppo sbatti" (trad: "Hai fatto bene, troppa fatica").

-Varianti : bella zì, bella lì, bella raga, bella storia. Esiste anche "ZIA" per le ragazze, insomma per le zie.

-Utilizzo: fra gli amici, ultra informale, poco elegante, amichevole, ghetto, ghetto-borghese - da evitare l'utilizzo in presenza di veri parenti onde evitare confusioni familiari. 
Attualmente il termine non è riconosciuto dall'Accademia della Crusca, cioè l'Istituto nazionale per la salvaguardia e lo studio della lingua italiana.

Comment: Da giovane lo sentivo usare anche con i nomi propri, a mo' di saluto: "bella Beppe!" dicevano gli amici a Beppe (Giuseppe) quando arrivava. Non so se questa forma sia ancora usata. In tutti i casi è sicuramente regionale.

Comment: Da piccolo, nel tempo del culto dei cosidetti "paninari" (forse qualcuno si ricorda quello stupido movimento che incitava la gente a rubare gli stemmini della Mercedes e della Volkswagen ed indossarli, e anche a comperare abiti di moda come quelli della Best Company, una marca che vendeva vestiti fatti di materiali adatti solo a fabbricare stracci ma a prezzi assurdamente alti, ed a mangiare panini nello stesso modo nel quale l'hamburger andava di moda nell'America), "zio" era proprio l'equivalente dell'Americano "bro" presumibilmente notoriamente diffuso da Giovanotti ed altri "paninari".

Comment: non avete spiegato cosa vuol dire bella. Ovvio per noi ma non per loro. Al femminile poi. Sottointeso di: " bella cosa hai fatto/detto", forse?

Comment: Nessuna ha spiegato il significato di bella. E' la parte più difficile per i non italiani. Perchè bella al femminile? Chi è bella? È al femminile perchè è bella ha sottinteso ("understood" in English) "bella cosa hai fatto/detto". Vivo negli USA da tanti anni e aggiungerei che l'equivalente americano di "Bella zio" è "sweet bro". Per noi Italiani è na bella cosa, per gli americani e una cosa letteralmente "dolce", ma col senso generale di "piacevole"

Comment: Benvenuto/benvenuta! Questo non è un forum, ma un sito di domande e risposte e non si possono accettare domande nello spazio delle risposte. Questo post verrà convertito in un commento. Niente paura! Si impara solo frequentando il sito.

Comment: ma non avete capito il senso del mio messaggio. Stavo riproponendo la domanda fatta dall`autore in modo retorico. Ho ripostato in maniera affermativa se questo era ambiguo.

Comment: @Millemila D'accordo, ma così la risposta è incompleta.

Comment: A proposito dell'uso di "zio", credo dipenda dall'uso che se ne fa(ceva) in Italia meridionale appellativo per le persone conosciute, generalmente anziane, nei confronti delle quali si prova rispetto e/o reverenza (vedi, ad esempio "zio Crocifisso" ne "I Malavoglia"). Probabilmente è entrato nell'espressione "bella, zio!", usato in senso ironico ma, man mano che l'uso dell'appellativo "zio" nella sua accezione rispettosa è andato scemando, si è perso anche il suo intento ironico nell'espressione "bella, zio!". [continua...]

Comment: [...] Penso che la sovrapposizione con l'inglese americano "bro" sia successiva e sia avvenuta proprio perché ormai quasi nessuno avesse idea del significato di quello "zio".

Comment: Non è molto convincente l'evoluzione del saluto Bella. Passare da "Zio Bello" a "Bella zio"...Perckè non "Bello zio" ?

Comment: @AntonioBarella perché "bella" non è riferito a "zio" (che è usato come vocativo e richiederebbe la virgola) ma alla situazione: "bella (situazione), zio!"

Answer (score 3):

In inglese equivale al "hey bro".

Si tratta del saluto milanese in voga tra i giovani (vorrei specificare che non riguarda TUTTI i giovani italiani. Qui ci si riferisce per la maggior parte ai milanesi, anche se conosco persone in città come Roma e Bologna che lo dicono). 
È decisamente più informale di ciao. La si usa per suonare simpatici e diretti. A mio parere, se usata con persone che non si conoscono molto bene, suona troppo informale e maleducato.

Letteralmente significa:

```
**Bella** ("ciao" o "hei" o "ueii", ecc) **zio** (socio, cumpà, amico, ecc).
```

Comment: L'ho sentita anche a Milano

Answer (score 1):

Cerco di rispondere alla domanda sul senso dell'espressione.

Nessuno ha spiegato il significato di "bella", fondamentale per capire "bella, zio". È la parte più difficile per i non italiani, che non capiscono perché è al femminile. È al femminile perché "bella, zio" ha sottinteso ("understood" in English) "hai fatto/detto", quindi è una abbreviazione della frase: "bella cosa hai fatto/detto, zio". Vivo negli USA da tanti anni e aggiungerei che l'equivalente americano di "bella, zio" è "sweet, bro". Per noi italiani è una bella cosa, per gli americani è una cosa letteralmente "dolce", ma col senso generale di "piacevole".

Answer (score 0):

Sono di Roma e da ben 47 anni. A Roma si è sempre detto BELLA REGA' (regazzi » ragazzi) o anche il più volgare BELLA RIGA'. 'Bella' sta per 'come va, tutto a posto, eccomi sono arrivato, bentrovati'. Quel 'Bella' è stato poi prelevato dal gergo nordico/milanese e il REGA' è stato sostituito da RAGA.
Sempre a Milano, suppongo, è stato portato il ZIO al posto di RAGA, che poi a Roma è diventato BELLA ZI', anche se questa è solo una trasformazione recente.

Da Almeno 40 anni a Roma si dice BELLA in questa accezione appena descitta.

Answer (score -1):

Ho vissuto gli anni novanta pieno di neologismi fatti dai giovani e l'unico che mi ricordo abbia resistito è "hai toppato"! Per quanto riguarda sempre i miei anni nel nord Italia si usa spesso l'imprecazione "porco zio", "bella zio" è un'espressione del milanese che personalmente penso possa avere attinenza.

Comment: Sei italiano madrelingua?

Comment: “Toppare” è una parola italiana che risale al XVI secolo.

Comment: Mi spieghi l’attinenza tra porco zio e bella zio, sono curioso.

Comment: Io sono milanese, ho sentito in giro entrambe le espressioni ma penso che non c'entrino nulla l'una con l'altra, "bella zio" è un'espressione giocosa, di apprezzamento, a volte anche un saluto, mentre l'altra è semplicemente una bestemmia mascherata.

Answer (score -4):

Nel 1996 uscì nelle sale un film con Diego Abatantuono (“il barbiere di Rio”) in cui Abatantuono veniva chiamato dai brasiliani “zio bello”...in quegli anni io ed un mio amico eravamo a Roma da studenti universitari e cominciammo a chiamarci tra di noi “zio bello”...spesso sentivamo dire “Bella fratè!”...ci venne in mente di sostituire “fratè” con “zio”...così anziché dire “zio bello” abbiamo cominciato a dire “bella zio!”.
Non vorrei dire una cavolata, ma credo che l’espressione “bella zio” e “bella zì” l’abbiamo coniata noi per gioco...divenne in poco un must nella nostra cerchia di amici...era appunto il 1996